# Can I get a CSV file with Android Market comments from users?

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know of a way to get a dump or the user comments for my App?  Right now I am copying and pasting from the Developer Console but would love to get a CSV of all the comments for easy searching / sorting, etc.

Thanks,
Tim